# Нужно ли использовать экранирование PHP при приеме данных?

Tags: php, безопасность, экранирование

Есть методы: `htmlspecialchars` и `htmlentities`. Как я понимаю, их надо использовать при выводе чего-то клиенту.

Методы `stripslashes` и `addslashes` нужны для удаления и добавления экранирования соответственно.

Есть также метод `quotemeta`, который экранирует специальные символы `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] ( $ )`.

Я пишу помощник (хелпер), который будет работать с входными и выходными данными. Не понимаю когда и как использовать эти методы.

При работе с базой все достаточно понятно: есть подготовленные запросы, которые спасают от нехороший ситуаций. А вот с данными, которые не попадают в базу, а обрабатываться на сервер и возвращаются - не ясно.

Вопрос такой: когда и как использовать указанные методы на стороне сервера? Нужно при получении данных применять вышеуказанные методы?

Comment: Для начала нужно понимать, от чего защищаемся. Защищаемся от XSS - используем htmlspecialchars при выводе; защищаемся от sql-инъекций - используем подготовленные выражения. А addslashes зачем нужен? А quotemeta от чего спасает? Если ни от чего - значит нет никакого смысла их использовать. Также нет никакого смысла использовать htmlspecialchars в sql-запросах, потому что в sql-запросах не бывает никакого xss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разберитесь как работают XSS атаки (от которых защищаетесь с помощью `htmlspecialchars`), SQL-инъекции (которых избегаете подготовленными выражениями). Все ухищрения нужны в случае, вы передаёте данные в другую систему (браузер, база данных), и эта система не разделяет данные и не данные (HTML и куски текста, SQL и значения). Именно в таких случаях нужно экранирование.

Например, вы используете данные в регулярном выражении `"~^/path/$dirName$~"`. Экранирование необходимо, потому что регулярка будет парсить данные также как и другие части регулярного выражения (правильно будет использовать preg_quote). То же с sprintf-шаблонами. Или, допустим, вы добавляете данные в ворд-документ, или в свой парсер DSL или просто цитируете меня и не хотите вставить между кавычек мой текст "`замечательные слова". Однако я демонстрирую неадекватность: "PHP - отвратительный яп!`".

Кроме того, имейте ввиду что экранировать надо не только пользовательские данные, а любые данные. Например если написать так `<div><?= '...не забудьте закрыть тэг: </div>' ?></div>`, то всё равно получится плохо (хотя данные не пользовательские).

При получении данных очищать и экранировать их не надо. Очищать и экранировать их надо при использовании. И только от использования зависит как именно надо их очищать и экранировать. Не пытайтесь придумать решение на все случаи жизни.

Кстати, обратите внимание на [стандартную библиотеку фильтров](https://www.php.net/filter), может быть там уже есть всё необходимое.

Answer (score 0):

В отрыве от реальной задачи трудно говорить о нужности определённых проверок.

Например, при работе с XML нужно экранировать/декодировать HTML-символы (htmlspecialchars/html_entity_decode)